# Program freezes when reading large inputs using cin

Tags: c++, input, cin

I have a problem while reading input in my program using `cin`. The input looks like this:

```
5 2
10 17 17 17 37
```

Where 5 is the number of items and 2 is the number of dividers (not relevant to this question). Both lines end with an end of line character.

The problem is when the number of items gets bigger then approximately 500 and the numbers get larger as well (instead of 17 something like 50356), `cin` stops (it simply freezes the entire program) somewhere while reading the large input. The strange thing is that it works perfectly on small inputs (my program does exactly what i expect) but not with larger inputs. I would also like to run it with input sizes > 5000. I have no clue why it does not work. Maybe there is a buffer problem and I need to flush. The solution is probably extremely simple.

```
void fill()
{
    cin >> numberOfItems;
    cin >> dividers;

    vector<unsigned long int> roundedSum;
    roundedSum.resize(numberOfItems);
    unRoundedSum.resize(numberOfItems);
    currentSum.resize(numberOfItems);
    updatedSum.resize(numberOfItems);

    unsigned long int tempValue;
    cin >> tempValue;

    roundedSum[0] = roundValue(tempValue);
    unRoundedSum[0] = tempValue;

    for (unsigned long int i = 1; i < numberOfItems; ++i){
        cin >> tempValue;
        tempValue += unRoundedSum[i - 1];
        unRoundedSum[i] = tempValue;
        roundedSum[i] = roundValue(unRoundedSum[i]);
    }
    currentSum = roundedSum;
    updatedSum = roundedSum;
}
```

**Edit: problem solved**
The problem was not with the `cin` function but with the way i gave the program the input. Pasting the enormous ammount of input on to clipboard and then put it as an argument in the terminal when running the program seams to be the problem. When running the program as `./program < input.in` where input.in is the file which holds all the input in the format as has been describe above, then the programs runs fine and does not freeze anymore.

Comment: Are you sure you passed all 500 items to the stdin?

Comment: Yes i am sure. I am running the program using the linux terminal like ./program and then the input. It works great with smaller inputs but not with larger

Comment: maybe its not the cin but the complexity of work you are doing in the loop which is slowing you down.

please try commenting out the work done in loop, and just try to read the values.

Comment: Try `for (size_t i = 1; i < numberOfItems &&  cin >> tempValue; ++i){` and get rid of `cin >> tempValue;` from inside the loop

Comment: When proceeding unbounded input, use a method that doesn't require knowing the number of items up front.  I would use an end of file condition for this myself.  That's also how a program like `cat` does it, so it's a standard method.

Comment: I tried the method of @KillzoneKid. but it did not work. I also tried to uncomment everything else but still the same issue.

Comment: I tried to use the function std::getline to see if i was able to print the entire list of items. However it is unable to give me the entire line back. It stops somewhere on one third of the input (the size of my input was 2500).

Comment: I think you have a flaw in your calculation of the sum formula. You essentially is doing `n += n;` It wont take long before you hit limits of `unsigned long`. For example if `n` is 1 you need only 32 loops to overflow.

Comment: I've added the minimal includes and definitions to make the code compile and run, and couldn't reproduce the problem. It runs fine with 500000 input values as large as 100000. Can you show the definition of the `roundValue` function? I've used a function that does nothing as substitute, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: The round function does nothing weird. In this case it only returns the value which is given to him as a parameter. I changed the code to 
    for (unsigned long int i = 1; i < numberOfItems; ++i){
        unsigned long int x;
        cin >> x;
    }

but still no effect. It still freezes. I also changed environment.

Comment: I feel so extremely stupid but apparently pasting with clipboard was the problem. If i executed the program as "./program < input.in" then it works perfectly and there is no problem. Thanks for your help and inputs on my code!

Comment: @ThomasNobel If you solved your problem, then write it up as an _answer_ and post that instead of editing your answer into your _question_. Stackoverflow is not a forum and has certain rules that users are expected to follow.

Comment: Yes i know. Thanks for the reminder. I will set it on solve in 5 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved. The problem was not with the `cin` function but with the way i gave the program the input. Pasting the enormous ammount of input on to clipboard and then put it as an argument in the terminal when running the program seams to be the problem. When running the program as `./program < input.in` where 'input.in' is the file which holds all the input in the format as has been describe above, then the programs runs fine and does not freeze anymore.